# Errors when installin node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I had a problem with a specific extension in React, so i deleted node_module and reinstall it :  `sudo npm install`

When the installation is finished, i had these errors (sorry it's too long, i just put a few lines) :

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /home/machemlal/Documents/FATB/fatboar/Website/node_modules/uws
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! make : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/machemlal/Documents/FATB/fatboar/Website/node_modules/uws/build »
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Extensions.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Group.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Networking.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Hub.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Node.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/WebSocket.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/HTTPSocket.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/Socket.o
    npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/uws/src/addon.o
    npm ERR! make : on quitte le répertoire « /home/machemlal/Documents/FATB/fatboar/Website/node_modules/uws/build »
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.19.1 | linux | x64
    npm ERR! gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/12.19.1"
    npm ERR! gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/tmp/.node-gyp"
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/machemlal/Documents/FATB/fatboar/Website/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args    
   ...
   ....
   ..
   etc..
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to run npm using sudo. See this doc on how to set things up correctly https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory

Comment: hello @m90, it also does not work without sudo, same errors..

Comment: You need to set up a few things on your system before it works without sudo (see the npm documentation). When your system is set up correctly there should be no reason to use sudo with npm ever.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Mr. i use linux

Comment: @m90 i used it without sudo, just `npm install` but it doesn't work